# After update to 3.6.2 no intall plugins are visible even not in "discover"

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, installation, joomla-3.6

I wanted to reinstall the plugins via the "discover" button, but they do not appear there at all.

Do you have any suggestions how I can reinstall the install-plugins manually without the discover-button?

Thank you very much for your support in advance!

**UPDATE**

And if I click on Extensions/Install - there is this message displayed:

> Warning
>
> No installation plugin has been enabled. At least one must be enabled
>   to be able to use the installer. Go to the Plugin Manager to enable
>   the plugins.

But in the plugins manager there are absolutely no install-plugins to be found - nor in the "discover" folder

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try downloading fresh copy of Joomla 3.6.2, unzip on local, and manually upload the files from that folder.  Then try discover again.

Answer (score 0):

All the standard plugins are in the 'plugins' folder in the Joomla 3.6.2 .zip file, but if your install's gone that wrong they're not showing up I'd either test using another install as I mentioned above, or copy the entire Joomla zip over to your installed Joomla directory.

Are all the other extensions (modules, components etc?) showing up properly in their respective tabs and the 'Extension Manager', or are they missing as well? Could be a problem with your database.

Comment: No all other plugins are there.
As Joomla said after the upgrade, that there are no working install-plugins, I went over to the manager and deleted the messy install plugins. Normally after that the good ones are visible in the "discover" area - but not this time. I'Äll have a try with the copy-thing...

Comment: Aye, your install is definitely messed up. If the copy thing doesn't work, check the 'extensions' table in your database and make sure the plugins are showing up in there.

Comment: Actually, just noticed you said you deleted the plugins using the extensions manager. In that case their database entries will have been removed - you'll need to insert them again yourself, manually repackage the plugin zips and install those, or - best option - completely reinstall Joomla.

Comment: @Creak You are giving some good advice, but having said that, try to clarify things by using comments (rather than asking in your answers) and combine your answers into one answer(by editing your first answer and deleting the others). Posting multiple answers is ok when the solutions are vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message you get indicates that all the installer plugins are disabled in the Plugin manager. I've seen this happen a few times after upgrades, without any apparent reason.

The solution is to go to your plugin manager (<kbd>Extensions</kbd> -> <kbd>Plugins</kbd>) and enter "install" in the search box.

Make sure at least one of the ***Installer - ...*** plugins are enabled.

[image: Installer plugins]

If any/all of the plugins have a red X under status, just click the button to enable the plugin.